# Want to assert that the values are not duplicated in the list

Tags: karate

I'm asserting a response like this using karate.

```
"Ids": ["123456","123456","123457"]
```

Now I want to assert that my list doesn't contain the duplicate values (If there is a duplicate value, it should fail the test-case), is there any in built function which is supported by Karate or is there any JS who does the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#karate-distinct

```
* def response = ["123456","123456","123457"]
* match response == karate.distinct(response)
```