# want to assert inner list in karate

Tags: karate

I have this kind of response in my API and I want to check that any of the list doesn't contain duplicate values.

```
[["1100","1100"],["123456"],["123456"],["123456"],["123516","110011"],["123515","110010"],["123514","110009"],["123513","110008"]]
```

when I use `* match response == karate.distinct(response)` , it compares all the values and not the values within the inner list like below

```
[["1100","2200"],["123456"],["123516","110011"],["123515","110010"],["123514","110009"],["123513","110008"]]
```

I only want to check whether inner list doesn't contain duplicate values, regardless of outer list elements.

This is the parent question https://stackoverflow.com/a/71807872/3664382, but now I'm stuck here -

Answer (score 0):

Use `match each`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#match-each

And combine it with a "self" validation: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#self-validation-expressions

```
* def fun = function(x){ return karate.match(x, karate.distinct(x)).pass }
* match each response == '#? fun(_)'
```

I have no idea how people end up with these weird situations. Please read this and I hope it makes sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

For completeness, you should take some time to understand JsonPath. This below will "flatten" the entire response into a single array:

```
* def temp = $response[*][*]
```

Comment: generally we don't test these weird situations, but this has to be done in order to validate and automate a defect that came up recently. by the way, I'm not able to connect the dots here.

Comment: @thisisdude I'm unable to explain my answer more. hopefully someone else will help